# Assign values from one array to another without looping

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way like in MATLAB to assign many values in an array's row?

Let's say you have a matrix M(5,5) and a Vector V = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In Matlab, If you wanted the first row to be filled up with vector V, you would write:

```
M(1,:) = V
```

Is there something similar in Excel VBA instead of looping through each column of the first row and assign the value V(j) every time?

Comment: No you cannot do that in straight VBA.  However [Functions For VBA Arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm) provides a host of useful functions.  It offers `GetRow` but not `SetRow`.  A little recoding should give the routine you seek.

Comment: Tony thank you very much for this link, it is really helpful! 
I am now switching from MATLAB to Excel, and I see some tasks that are really easy in other languages, have to be hard-coded in Excel!

Comment: MATLAB is an example of a specialist language. Within its specialty, it provides powerful and easy to use functionality but provides little or no functionality outside that specialty.  VBA is a general purpose language.  Many programming tasks can be tackled with VBA but it is only really good at providing access to Excel worksheets.  I use both VBA and VB.Net.  I use VBA for the easy stuff and Excel access.  I use VB.Net for the fast processing and enormous library of functions.  The Express version of VB.Net is free so why not give it a try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189984/excel-vba-add-1-dimensional-array-to-multi-dimensional-array-without-looping

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines:

```
Sub InitializeMatrixWithVector()

Dim V(), M()
ReDim M(1 To 5, 1 To 5)

V = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
M = Application.Choose([1+(row(1:5)=1)], M, V)

Range("B1").Resize(UBound(M), UBound(M, 2)) = M

End Sub
```

- The square brackets are equivalent to the `Evaluate` VBA function.
- `Application.Choose` is a WorksheetFunction method that can take and return variant arrays.