# VBA adding an array to another array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm super new to VBA (and stack overflow, this is my first post) and I'm trying to simplify my code, but I just cannot seem to find a way to add an 1D array to 3D array in 1 line.
I have 3 dimensional array

```
Dim myArray(50, 20, 3) As Variant
```

Currently I have to do this:

```
myArray(0, 0, 0) = 0: myArray(0, 0, 1) = 1: myArray(0, 0, 2) = 2
```

You can see how I have actually 3 statements in 1 line and I had to type the array name 3 times.
What I would instead like to do is something like this:

```
myArray(0, 0) = {0,1,2}
```

End result should be the same.

Comment: Hello! Have you tried other SO answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189984/excel-vba-add-1-dimensional-array-to-multi-dimensional-array-without-looping)?

Comment: The description of the VB.NET and VBA tags explicitly state that they are different languages and that neither tag should be used for the other language. Being new to a programming language doesn't mean you're new to the internet or reading. Don't spam tags.

Comment: I've added an answer and then re-read your question (yes I completely missed your point of 1 line) - Why do you want to add all elements of the 3rd dimension in 1 line?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry about that, I completely missed the description of the tags and I just assumed that VB.NET would have same syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS my other answer is a valid option, I thought I'd leave it in but to achieve what you are wanting to do in 1 line you can do like so:

Declare your Array as 2D:

```
Dim myArray(50,20) As Variant
```

Then you create a 3rd dimension by assigning an array to the 2nd dimension, like so:

```
myArray(0,0) = Array(0,1,2,3)
```

Before:
[image: Before adding Array to 2nd dimension]

And After:
[image: After adding Array to 2nd dimension]

Note to access this (as it's an array within the array) you would do so like this in the immediate pane - note the syntax:

```
?myArray(0,0)(0)
 0
?myArray(0,0)(1)
 1 
?myArray(0,0)(2)
 2 
?myArray(0,0)(3)
 3
```

I'm not aware of any effects this *may* have with stability or performance but it's *a* solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`For...Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) loop like so:

```
Sub test()
Dim myArray(50, 30, 3)
Dim ArrayElement As Long

For ArrayElement = 0 To (UBound(myArray, 3))
    myArray(0, 0, ArrayElement) = ArrayElement
Next ArrayElement

End Sub
```

To take the other dimensions into account, nest more loops, like;

```
For 1DElement = 0 To Ubound(myArray, 1)
    For 2DElement = 0 To Ubound(MyArray, 2)
        For 3DElement= 0 To (UBound(myArray, 3))
            myArray(0, 0, 3DElement) = 3DElement
        Next 3DElement
    'Add code here to change 2D elements if need be
    Next 2DElement
    ''Add code here to change 1D elements if need be
Next 1DElement
```

`Ubound(myArray, 1)` for example is the upper bound of the 1st dimension. Natrually 2 and 3 are the 2nd and 3rd dimensions, and so on. [Ubound documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)